# Catching vs. not catching specific error types in dart - any difference in behavior?

Tags: dart, error-handling

My understanding of catching errors was that if a certain error is 'caught', the code in a method following the `catch` block would not execute unless you have a `finally` statement afterwards.

However, if I catch a certain error type, but don't have a `return` or a `throw`/`rethrow` statement at the end, it does seem to keep going with the further code in the method.

I am catching a certain exception type, with the statement `on CustomException catch (error)` but I'm not planning to rethrow the error, and I don't need to do anything with the actual error. I don't have a `return` or a `rethrow` statement, as I assumed the catch block. I have two questions to make sure I'm understanding this behavior properly:

First question - if I don't plan to use the specific error inside my catch block, does adding `catch (error)` after `on CustomException` actually make a difference? It seems like it's ok to do it with or without it.

Second question - does my catch block need to have a return/throw/rethrow statement at the end in *all cases* to prevent the method from performing any further code?

Code example 1: With the catch (error) statement:

```
try {
    ...
} on CustomException catch (error) {
    ...
} catch (error) {
    rethrow;
}
print('Is this method still running?');
```

Code example 2: without the catch (error) statement:

```
try {
    ...
} on CustomException {
    ...
} catch (error) {
   rethrow;
}

print('Is this method still running?');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples aren't the same; one catches `CustomException` and the other catches `PlatformException`.  Presuming that you meant them to be the same, then the difference between `on CustomException` and `on CustomException catch (error)` is that the second way allows you to do something with the thrown object (or if you use `on CustomException catch (error, stacktrace)`, to do something with the stacktrace too).

[The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch) covers this:

> Use `on` when you need to specify the exception type. Use `catch` when your exception handler needs the exception object.

Additionally, doing:

```dart
catch (error) {
  rethrow;
}
```

is unnecessary noise.  Just omit it and let the thrown exception go uncaught.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin. Fixed to make the exceptions use the same type. That definitely answers the on/catch question. But just to confirm, if the on/catch block doesn't either throw an error or contain a return statement, the rest of the code in the method will be executed in both of those cases, right?

Comment: @CharliePage Right, catching an exception will allow the rest of the function to execute unless you explicitly break normal control flow via `return`, `throw`, or some less common ways.